# Link a gallery photo to a page without breaking JQuery animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry, modernizr, lightgallery

In the showcase section of [this page](https://www.styleshout.com/demo/?theme=infinity) (featured projects area), I am trying to link each photo to a dedicated page, instead of going into the JQuery light box.

Is there a way to achieve this without breaking the fade up animations and the dark overlays already present before clicking? Totally okay with scrapping the lightbox feature if neccessary, but not sure what to delete in fear of breaking the design and function.

This is a template that I have already customized with html and css. The linking to a page is the only issue I can't figure out (I'm a newby to JavaScript).

Any input would be much appreciated.

The entire site is downloadable with the style and JavaScript files for you to tinker with.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: There's probably a `click` event with `preventDefault` to show the lightbox. Just remove that and add the URL to the anchor.

Comment: @azeós Thank you for the advice, I'll do a search and try that out.